# JSON parameter not being passed when calling an API from php

Tags: php, json, api, post

I am trying to make an API call from **PHP** using **post** method. One of the parameters requires a JSON string. I am trying to use **json_encode** to convert an array to JSON but still am not receiving the contents of this parameter on the server side. Below is the code that I wrote.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>API testing</h1>

<?php
$myData = array("data1" => "my_data_1",
                "data2" => "my_data_2"
                );
$myData = json_encode($myData);
$data = array (
    'NAME' => 'testPHP',
    'TYPE' => 'xyz',
    'DATA' => $myData
);
$data = http_build_query($data);

$context_options = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $data
        )
    );
$context = stream_context_create($context_options);
$result = file_get_contents("https://myurl.com", false, $context);
echo $result;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I receive all the parameters successfully but only the value of the parameter **DATA** is sent as ******. I tried to change the **Content-type** in headers to **application/json** but this makes it even worse because I receive none of the parameters server side. Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Dumping $data is showing correctly: 
"string(94) "NAME=testPHP&TYPE=xyz&DATA=%7B%22data1%22%3A%22my_data_1%22%2C%22data2%22%3A%22my_data_2%22%7D"

Comment: I would suggest using curl instead as it is better suited to send post requests with a body than file_get_contents

Comment: I need to do this without using curl for some reason. Is this a bug because of which the parameters is not being passed or I am doing something wrong here ?